# integrate nopcommerce into webform project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, integration, membership-provider, nopcommerce

I have an asp.net website (web form) with login area and general information. I would like to link/integrate a webshop made with nopcommerce. I know that nopcommerce is MVC, so I'd like to create a second website (mvc) only for the shop and link/redirect the user to this site.

Is it possible to use the login information (I use a standard membership provider) already created for the web forms page for the shop or does the user need to have a separate login for nopcommerce? 
Would it be better or is it possible to integrate my web forms project into the nopcommerce project (or vice versa) and make it all one website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 possible ways to integrate your website with nop commerce.

1. By Writing an external authentication plugin

Assuming your master customer data stored on your website. So nop commerce will authenticate against that and creates customer profile automatically. Writing external authentication plugin wont be an issue as there are few authentication plugins to referr. Example: Facebook authentication or open id authentication which comes as part of nop commerce package with code. Then modify registration page of nop commcere to hide sign up part. This way your customer login data stays with you. but still customer will be able to authenticate and redirect to nop commerce website.

2. By merging your website with nop commerce.

Migrate your customer data to nop commerce and merge your website with nop commerce. this will gives you flexibility on updates and maintenance. To migrate your customer data, you can use sql server SSIS Packages.

I would choose option 2 if possible. It would be hard in the first place, but saves lots of troubles in long run.